# Implementing DirectX SDK sample(XAudio2Sound3D) gives me an unresolved external error?

Tags: directx, unresolved-external, xaudio2

When I implement the XAudio2Sound3D sample from the June 2010 SDK.I pretty much copied it all in my own framework and this one variable(**sound3DInstance**) shows up as an unresolved external: *X3DAudioCalculate(**sound3DInstance**, &listener, &emitter, calcFlags, &dspSettings);* and *X3DAudioInitialize(details.OutputFormat.dwChannelMask, SPEEDOFSOUND, **sound3DInstance**);*
Where the variable types are:

```
X3DAUDIO_HANDLE sound3DInstance;
X3DAUDIO_LISTENER listener;
X3DAUDIO_EMITTER emitter;
X3DAUDIO_DSP_SETTINGS dspSettings;
DWORD calcFlags = X3DAUDIO_CALCULATE_MATRIX | X3DAUDIO_CALCULATE_DOPPLER | X3DAUDIO_CALCULATE_LPF_DIRECT | X3DAUDIO_CALCULATE_LPF_REVERB | X3DAUDIO_CALCULATE_REVERB;
const float SPEEDOFSOUND = X3DAUDIO_SPEED_OF_SOUND;
XAUDIO2_DEVICE_DETAILS details;
```

Now the only common variable in both functions that show the error is **sound3DInstance**,so that has to be the problem.In the SDK Sample all the variables are put in a struct called *AUDIO_STATE* and in the initialization of the program,they call:
*ZeroMemory( &g_audioState, sizeof( AUDIO_STATE ) );*
In my code the variables are members of my Sound class and I just ZeroMemory them one by one,so shouldn't the effect be the same?

Answer (score 0):

You're not linking your program against the XAudio library (Xaudio2.lib). Check the linker settings for your project.

Comment: oh,I can't believe I forgot the .lib (facepalm) just 1 thing...it also wants a XAudio2_8.dll,but I can't find such a file anywhere in my SDK?Is it supposed to be downloaded seperately?